# Parcelling complex objects b/w activities in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, serialization, parcelable

I have a complex  class "Class11" containing Socket,PrintWriter class references.
I am getting exception while trying to pass it between activities.

```
  public interface Interface11 extends Parcelable{
    ...........
    }

    public class Class11 implements Interface11 {
       Socket clientSocket;
       ServerSocket serverSocket;

    PrintWriter writer;
          BufferedReader reader;
       private JChatConnection(Parcel in) {

               Object [] objects= in.readArray(Object.class.getClassLoader());
               clientSocket=(Socket) objects[0];
               serverSocket=(ServerSocket) objects[1];
               writer=(PrintWriter) objects[2];
               reader=(BufferedReader) objects[3];

            }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {

        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        Object objects[] = new Object[4];

            objects[0]=clientSocket;
            objects[1]=serverSocket;
            objects[2]=writer;
            objects[3]=reader;

        dest.writeArray(objects);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Class11> CREATOR = 
new Parcelable.Creator<Class11>() {
            public Class11 createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Class11(in);
            }

            public Class11[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Class11[size];
            }
        };

};
```

though i have option of sharing it via static object reference,
but to reduce coupling i tried to pass it via intent,
& i got exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to marshall value Socket[address=/192.168.43.225,port=9990,localport=213234]
 at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1137)
 at android.os.Parcel.writeArray(Parcel.java: 543)........
```

- is it because  Socket ,PrintWriter are not parcellable or,
- am i messing this code at writeToParcel() and  private Class11(Parcel in)

anybody has idea that how to pass this object between activities ?

Comment: Just our of curiosity, do you also have Class1, Class2, Class3...in your app, or that's just a domain name?

Comment: this is a cruel attempt to hide the original name of my class !
- the secret 007 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not pass your object instance as an argument to Activity. Make it a Singleton, or a member of Application class. That will allow you to access Class11 instance everywhere in your app.